# Find a compact (close form) expression based upon the binomial theorem for the polynomials $\sum\limits_{0 \leq 2k \leq n} {n \choose 2k}{x}^{2k}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, closed-form, binomial-theorem

Find a compact (close form) expression based upon the binomial theorem for the polynomials

$\sum\limits_{0 \leq 2k \leq n} {n \choose 2k}{x}^{2k}$ and $\sum\limits_{0 \leq 2k + 1 \leq n} {n \choose 2k + 1}{x}^{2k + 1}$

> Here is what I have so far:
> $$ = \sum\limits_{0 \leq 2k \leq n} {n \choose 2k}{x}^{2k}$$
> $$ = \sum\limits_{0 \leq 2k \leq n} {n \choose 2k}{x}^{2k} {1}^{n - 2k}$$
> $$ = {(x + 1)}^{n}$$
> and
> $$ = \sum\limits_{0 \leq 2k + 1 \leq n} {n \choose 2k + 1}{x}^{2k + 1}$$
> $$ = \sum\limits_{0 \leq 2k + 1 \leq n} {n \choose 2k + 1}{x}^{2k + 1} {1}^{n - 2k - 1}$$
> $$ = {(x + 1)}^{n}$$

Should both answers be the same or have I made a mistake?

Comment: These computations are wrong.  Start with some simple cases, $n=2,n=3,n=4$, say.

Comment: Hint: what should the two expressions add up to?

Comment: Is $n$ even or odd? If $n$ is odd, then the odd-numbered entries in row $n$ of Pascal's triangle are exactly a mirror image of the even-numbered entries (starting from $1$ as the $0$th entry) and both sums should equal $\frac{1}{2}(x+1)^n$. Otherwise, if $n$ is even, then it is not clear that the two sums are the same, although their sum should still be $(x+1)^n$.

Comment: Hint2: What is the difference of the two expressions?

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$(1 +x)^{n} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k 1^{n-k}$.
Note that this is not enough since we are interested only in the even powers of $x$.

Thus, we need to remove the odd powers of $x$. Consider,
$(1 - x)^{n} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k (-1)^{k}$.

Thus,
$(1 + x)^{n} + (1 - x)^{n} = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^k( 1 + (-1)^{k}) = 2\sum_{k=0}^{n/2} \binom{n}{2k}x^{2k}$.

Thus, we have $\sum_{0 \leq 2k \leq n} \binom{n}{2k}x^{2k} = \frac{1}{2}((1 + x)^{n} + (1 - x)^{n})$.

The formula for $\sum_{0 \leq 2k+1 \leq n} \binom{n}{2k+1}x^{2k+1}$ is obtaine in the same fassion, or using the notion that
$\sum_{0 \leq 2k+1 \leq n} \binom{n}{2k+1}x^{2k+1} +  \sum_{0 \leq 2k \leq n} \binom{n}{2k}x^{2k} = (1 + x)^n$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Notice that both cases (even and odd $n$) can be written as one: $$\sum_{0\le2k\le n}\binom{n}{2k}x^{2k} = \tfrac{1}{2}((1+x)^n + (1-x)^n)$$

Comment: Thank you! Good point.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake OP made is that the first sum is the sum of the even powers while the second one is the sum of the odd powers as below:
\begin{align}
\sum_{0 \leqslant 2 k \leq n}\binom{n}{2 k}
x^{2 k}&= \binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{2}x^2+\binom{n}{4}x^4 +\dots+\binom{n}{2\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor}
x^{2\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\rfloor} \\
&\neq (x+1)^n \\
\sum_{0 \leqslant 2 k +1\leq n}\binom{n}{2 k+1}x^{2 k+1} &= \binom{n}{1}x+\binom{n}{3}x^3+\binom{n}{5} x^5 +\dots+\binom{n}{
2\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor+1}x^{2\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor+1} \\
&\neq (x+1)^n
\end{align}
Meanwhile $$\sum_{0 \leqslant 2 k \leq n}\binom{n}{2 k}
x^{2 k}+ \sum_{0 \leqslant 2 k +1\leq n}\binom{n}{2 k+1}x^{2 k+1}=(x+1)^n$$